# Why is the input field with the disabled attribute not saving the entered data at the field after submitting tha data and stepping back?

Tags: javascript

there.

I have the simplest form with the code:

```
<script>
var field1 = document.querySelector("#field1")
var field2 = document.querySelector("#field2")

field1.addEventListener('focus', function (e) {
    field2.removeAttribute("disabled")
})
</script>
<form action="/" method="POST">
    <input id="field1" name="field1" required="" type="text" value="">
    <input disabled="disabled" id="field2" name="field2" type="text" required="" value="">
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

After entering data, sending the form and stepping back, I see no data in the second field. Why?

**Before sending data:**

[image: before]

**After sending data and stepping back** in a browser history with a mouse back button:

[image: after]

Comment: Most likely because data in disabled fields will be excluded from what is being sent to the server upon form submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When sending data by clicking on the Save button, the values in both the `input` are being sent. But, when you step back you are effectively **reloading the page**. On reloading, two things are happening:

1. The page DOM is reset to its initial state i.e. to the markup in your HTML. Since, in your initial HTML markup, `field2` is set as `disabled`, on page reset the same thing happens.
2. The browser is autocompleting the previous values that were filled in the inputs. This is a feature of the browser itself and if it were not there, then even in the first field there would've been no data on stepping back. You could verify this by adding `autocomplete="off"` to the first input field.

Therefore, as your browser implements autocomplete on page reload (due to stepping back), the first input field is filled but the second input field is not because it is reset to its disabled state.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Is there a workaround without JS?

Comment: When you send the data, the values from both the input will be sent to the server. On stepping back (reloading) the inputs revert to their original state, but that does not change the data that is already sent to the server. So, I don't see any need for a workaround here because everything is working as it should be. Have I misunderstood your question here and you want to accomplish something else?